# Flask-SQLAlchemy, "Application not registered on db"

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following Flask app running on one machine:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from aves.extensions import db

def create_app(config_object=DevConfig):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://user:password@localhost/dbname'
    register_extensions(app)
    return app

def register_extensions(app):
    db.init_app(app)

    query = "SELECT * FROM score LIMIT 50;"
    result = db.engine.execute(query)
    print(list(result))

    return None
```

**extensions.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

Now, I used pgAdmin's backup function to export my database, and import it again to a new machine. I try to run the same code, but now I'm getting the following error:

`RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context`

I had the database running on the new machine before, then I worked on the code n the other machine for a while, and now that I try it again on the new one it doesn't work (maybe its somehow still bound to the old database or something?).

When I try a simple script like the one below and run it, it works fine.

**test_db_connection.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://user:password@localhost/dbname'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

query = "SELECT * FROM score LIMIT 50;"
result = db.engine.execute(query)
print(list(result))
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How to get it to run of course..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to run by adding the following line to **app.py**: `with app.app_context():`

```
def create_app(config_object=DevConfig):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    with app.app_context():
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://user:password@localhost/dbname'
        register_extensions(app)
        return app
```